# Opening storage failed" err="invalid block sequence"

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

**What did you do?**

```
 I ran prometheus2.0.0 on kubernetesv1.8.5
```

**What did you expect to see?**

```
 Everything went well.
```

**What did you see instead? Under which circumstances?**

Everything went well at beginning. But several hours later, pods' statuses turned to "CrashLoopBackOff", all prometheus turned unavaliable. After prometheus pods created, nothing has been done.

```
[root@k8s-1 prometheus]# kubectl get all -n monitoring
NAME                          DESIRED   CURRENT   AGE
statefulsets/prometheus-k8s   0         2         16h

NAME                  READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
po/prometheus-k8s-0   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   81         16h
po/prometheus-k8s-1   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   22         16h
```

**Environment**

```
[root@k8s-1 prometheus]# kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.8.5
Server Version: v1.8.5


[root@k8s-1 prometheus]# docker images | grep -i prometheus
quay.io/prometheus/alertmanager                          v0.12.0             f87cbd5f1360        5 weeks ago         31.2 MB
quay.io/prometheus/node_exporter                         v0.15.2             ff5ecdcfc4a2        6 weeks ago         22.8 MB
quay.io/prometheus/prometheus                            v2.0.0              67141fa03496        2 months ago        80.2 MB
```

- System information:

  [root@k8s-1 prometheus]# uname -srm

  Linux 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 x86_64
- Prometheus version:

  v2.0.0
- Prometheus configuration file:

  ```
  [root@k8s-1 prometheus]# cat prometheus-configmap.yaml 
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: ConfigMap
  metadata:
    name: prometheus-k8s-config
    namespace: monitoring
  data:
    prometheus.yaml: |
      global:
        scrape_interval: 10s
        scrape_timeout: 10s
        evaluation_interval: 10s
      rule_files:
        - "/etc/prometheus-rules/*.rules"

  scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'kubernetes-apiservers'
    kubernetes_sd_configs:
    - role: endpoints
    scheme: https

    tls_config:
      ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
    bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

    relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace, __meta_kubernetes_service_name, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name]
      action: keep
      regex: default;kubernetes;https

  - job_name: 'kubernetes-nodes'
    scheme: https

    tls_config:
      ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
    bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

    kubernetes_sd_configs:
    - role: node

    relabel_configs:
    - action: labelmap
      regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
    - target_label: __address__
      replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
      regex: (.+)
      target_label: __metrics_path__
      replacement: /api/v1/nodes/${1}/proxy/metrics

  - job_name: 'kubernetes-cadvisor'
    scheme: https
    tls_config:
      ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
    bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

    kubernetes_sd_configs:
    - role: node

    relabel_configs:
    - action: labelmap
      regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
    - target_label: __address__
      replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
      regex: (.+)
      target_label: __metrics_path__
      replacement: /api/v1/nodes/${1}/proxy/metrics/cadvisor

  - job_name: 'kubernetes-service-endpoints'

    kubernetes_sd_configs:
    - role: endpoints

    relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
      action: keep
      regex: true
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme]
      action: replace
      target_label: __scheme__
      regex: (https?)
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
      action: replace
      target_label: __metrics_path__
      regex: (.+)
    - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
      action: replace
      target_label: __address__
      regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
      replacement: $1:$2
    - action: labelmap
      regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
      action: replace
      target_label: kubernetes_namespace
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
      action: replace
      target_label: kubernetes_name

  - job_name: 'kubernetes-services'

    metrics_path: /probe
    params:
      module: [http_2xx]

    kubernetes_sd_configs:
    - role: service

    relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_probe]
      action: keep
      regex: true
    - source_labels: [__address__]
      target_label: __param_target
    - target_label: __address__
      replacement: blackbox-exporter.example.com:9115
    - source_labels: [__param_target]
      target_label: instance
    - action: labelmap
      regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
      target_label: kubernetes_namespace
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
      target_label: kubernetes_name

  - job_name: 'kubernetes-ingresses'

    metrics_path: /probe
    params:
      module: [http_2xx]

    kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: ingress

    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_ingress_annotation_prometheus_io_probe]
        action: keep
        regex: true
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_ingress_scheme,__address__,__meta_kubernetes_ingress_path]
        regex: (.+);(.+);(.+)
        replacement: ${1}://${2}${3}
        target_label: __param_target
      - target_label: __address__
        replacement: blackbox-exporter.example.com:9115
      - source_labels: [__param_target]
        target_label: instance
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_ingress_label_(.+)
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
        target_label: kubernetes_namespace
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_ingress_name]
        target_label: kubernetes_name

  - job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'

    kubernetes_sd_configs:
    - role: pod

    relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
      action: keep
      regex: true
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
      action: replace
      target_label: __metrics_path__
      regex: (.+)
    - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
      action: replace
      regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
      replacement: $1:$2
      target_label: __address__
    - action: labelmap
      regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
      action: replace
      target_label: kubernetes_namespace
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
      action: replace
      target_label: kubernetes_pod_name
  ```

prometheus.yaml:

```
    [root@k8s-1 prometheus]# cat prometheus-all-together.yaml
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      labels:
        prometheus: k8s
      name: prometheus-k8s
      namespace: monitoring
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
    spec:
      ports:
      - name: web
        nodePort: 30900
        port: 9090
        protocol: TCP
        targetPort: web
      selector:
        prometheus: k8s
      sessionAffinity: None
      type: NodePort
    ---
    apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
    kind: StatefulSet
    metadata:
      labels:
        prometheus: k8s
      name: prometheus-k8s
      namespace: monitoring
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: prometheus
          prometheus: k8s
      serviceName: prometheus-k8s
      replicas: 2
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: prometheus
            prometheus: k8s
        spec:
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 65534
            fsGroup: 65534
            runAsNonRoot: true
          containers:
          - args:
            - --config.file=/etc/prometheus/config/prometheus.yaml
            - --storage.tsdb.path=/cephfs/prometheus/data
            - --storage.tsdb.retention=180d
            - --web.route-prefix=/
            - --web.enable-lifecycle
            - --web.enable-admin-api
            image: quay.io/prometheus/prometheus:v2.0.0
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            livenessProbe:
              failureThreshold: 10
              httpGet:
                path: /status
                port: web
                scheme: HTTP
              initialDelaySeconds: 30
              periodSeconds: 5
              successThreshold: 1
              timeoutSeconds: 3
            name: prometheus
            ports:
            - containerPort: 9090
              name: web
              protocol: TCP
            readinessProbe:
              failureThreshold: 6
              httpGet:
                path: /status
                port: web
                scheme: HTTP
              periodSeconds: 5
              successThreshold: 1
              timeoutSeconds: 3
            resources:
              requests:
                cpu: 100m
                memory: 200Mi
              limits:
                cpu: 500m
                memory: 500Mi
            terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
            terminationMessagePolicy: File
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /etc/prometheus/config
              name: config
              readOnly: false
            - mountPath: /etc/prometheus/rules
              name: rules
              readOnly: false
            - mountPath: /cephfs/prometheus/data
              name: data
              subPath: prometheus-data
              readOnly: false
          serviceAccount: prometheus-k8s
          serviceAccountName: prometheus-k8s
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
          volumes:
          - configMap:
              defaultMode: 511
              name: prometheus-k8s-config
            name: config
          - configMap:
              defaultMode: 511
              name: prometheus-k8s-rules
            name: rules
          - name: data
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: cephfs-pvc
      updateStrategy:
        type: RollingUpdate
```

- Logs:

  ```
  [root@k8s-1 prometheus]# kubectl logs prometheus-k8s-0 -n monitoring
  level=info ts=2018-01-20T03:16:32.966070249Z caller=main.go:215 msg="Starting Prometheus" version="(version=2.0.0, branch=HEAD, revision=0a74f98628a0463dddc90528220c94de5032d1a0)"
  level=info ts=2018-01-20T03:16:32.966225361Z caller=main.go:216 build_context="(go=go1.9.2, user=root@615b82cb36b6, date=20171108-07:11:59)"
  level=info ts=2018-01-20T03:16:32.966252185Z caller=main.go:217 host_details="(Linux 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Mar 6 11:36:42 UTC 2015 x86_64 prometheus-k8s-0 (none))"
  level=info ts=2018-01-20T03:16:32.969789371Z caller=web.go:380 component=web msg="Start listening for connections" address=0.0.0.0:9090
  level=info ts=2018-01-20T03:16:32.971388907Z caller=main.go:314 msg="Starting TSDB"
  level=info ts=2018-01-20T03:16:32.971596811Z caller=targetmanager.go:71 component="target manager" msg="Starting target manager..."
  level=error ts=2018-01-20T03:16:59.781338012Z caller=main.go:323 msg="Opening storage failed" err="invalid block sequence: block time ranges overlap (1516348800000, 1516356000000)"
  [root@k8s-1 prometheus]# 
  [root@k8s-1 prometheus]# kubectl logs prometheus-k8s-1 -n monitoring
  level=info ts=2018-01-20T03:15:22.701351679Z caller=main.go:215 msg="Starting Prometheus" version="(version=2.0.0, branch=HEAD, revision=0a74f98628a0463dddc90528220c94de5032d1a0)"
  level=info ts=2018-01-20T03:15:22.70148418Z caller=main.go:216 build_context="(go=go1.9.2, user=root@615b82cb36b6, date=20171108-07:11:59)"
  level=info ts=2018-01-20T03:15:22.701512333Z caller=main.go:217 host_details="(Linux 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Mar 6 11:36:42 UTC 2015 x86_64 prometheus-k8s-1 (none))"
  level=info ts=2018-01-20T03:15:22.705824203Z caller=web.go:380 component=web msg="Start listening for connections" address=0.0.0.0:9090
  level=info ts=2018-01-20T03:15:22.707629775Z caller=main.go:314 msg="Starting TSDB"
  level=info ts=2018-01-20T03:15:22.707837323Z caller=targetmanager.go:71 component="target manager" msg="Starting target manager..."
  level=error ts=2018-01-20T03:15:54.775639791Z caller=main.go:323 msg="Opening storage failed" err="invalid block sequence: block time ranges overlap (1516348800000, 1516356000000)"




  [root@k8s-1 prometheus]# kubectl describe po/prometheus-k8s-0 -n monitoring
  Name:           prometheus-k8s-0
  Namespace:      monitoring
  Node:           k8s-3/172.16.1.8
  Start Time:     Fri, 19 Jan 2018 17:59:38 +0800
  Labels:         app=prometheus
                  controller-revision-hash=prometheus-k8s-7d86dfbd86
                  prometheus=k8s
  Annotations:    kubernetes.io/created-by={"kind":"SerializedReference","apiVersion":"v1","reference":{"kind":"StatefulSet","namespace":"monitoring","name":"prometheus-k8s","uid":"7593d8ac-fcff-11e7-9333-fa163e48f857"...
  Status:         Running
  IP:             10.244.2.54
  Created By:     StatefulSet/prometheus-k8s
  Controlled By:  StatefulSet/prometheus-k8s
  Containers:
    prometheus:
      Container ID:  docker://98faabe55fb71050aacd776d349a6567c25c339117159356eedc10cbc19ef02a
      Image:         quay.io/prometheus/prometheus:v2.0.0
      Image ID:      docker-pullable://quay.io/prometheus/prometheus@sha256:53afe934a8d497bb703dbbf7db273681a56677775c462833da8d85015471f7a3
      Port:          9090/TCP
      Args:
        --config.file=/etc/prometheus/config/prometheus.yaml
        --storage.tsdb.path=/cephfs/prometheus/data
        --storage.tsdb.retention=180d
        --web.route-prefix=/
        --web.enable-lifecycle
        --web.enable-admin-api
      State:          Waiting
        Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
      Last State:     Terminated
        Reason:       Error
        Exit Code:    1
        Started:      Sat, 20 Jan 2018 11:11:00 +0800
        Finished:     Sat, 20 Jan 2018 11:11:29 +0800
      Ready:          False
      Restart Count:  84
      Limits:
        cpu:     500m
        memory:  500Mi
      Requests:
        cpu:        100m
        memory:     200Mi
      Liveness:     http-get http://:web/status delay=30s timeout=3s period=5s #success=1 #failure=10
      Readiness:    http-get http://:web/status delay=0s timeout=3s period=5s #success=1 #failure=6
      Environment:  <none>
      Mounts:
        /cephfs/prometheus/data from data (rw)
        /etc/prometheus/config from config (rw)
        /etc/prometheus/rules from rules (rw)
        /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from prometheus-k8s-token-x8xzh (ro)
  Conditions:
    Type           Status
    Initialized    True 
    Ready          False 
    PodScheduled   True 
  Volumes:
    config:
      Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
      Name:      prometheus-k8s-config
      Optional:  false
    rules:
      Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
      Name:      prometheus-k8s-rules
      Optional:  false
    data:
      Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
      ClaimName:  cephfs-pvc
      ReadOnly:   false
    prometheus-k8s-token-x8xzh:
      Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
      SecretName:  prometheus-k8s-token-x8xzh
      Optional:    false
  QoS Class:       Burstable
  Node-Selectors:  <none>
  Tolerations:     node.alpha.kubernetes.io/notReady:NoExecute for 300s
                   node.alpha.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
  Events:
    Type     Reason      Age                  From            Message
    ----     ------      ----                 ----            -------
    Normal   Pulled      15m (x83 over 17h)   kubelet, k8s-3  Container image "quay.io/prometheus/prometheus:v2.0.0" already present on machine
    Warning  FailedSync  23s (x1801 over 7h)  kubelet, k8s-3  Error syncing pod
  ```

logs on kubernetes nodes:

```
    [root@k8s-3 01C48JAGH1QCGKGCG72E0B2Y8R]# journalctl -xeu kubelet --no-pager
    1月 20 11:21:54 k8s-3 kubelet[14306]: I0120 11:21:54.619924   14306 kuberuntime_manager.go:749] Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=prometheus pod=prometheus-k8s-0_monitoring(7598959a-fcff-11e7-9333-fa163e48f857)
    1月 20 11:21:54 k8s-3 kubelet[14306]: E0120 11:21:54.620042   14306 pod_workers.go:182] Error syncing pod 7598959a-fcff-11e7-9333-fa163e48f857 ("prometheus-k8s-0_monitoring(7598959a-fcff-11e7-9333-fa163e48f857)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "prometheus" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=prometheus pod=prometheus-k8s-0_monitoring(7598959a-fcff-11e7-9333-fa163e48f857)"
    1月 20 11:22:08 k8s-3 kubelet[14306]: I0120 11:22:08.615438   14306 kuberuntime_manager.go:500] Container {Name:prometheus Image:quay.io/prometheus/prometheus:v2.0.0 Command:[] Args:[--config.file=/etc/prometheus/config/prometheus.yaml --storage.tsdb.path=/cephfs/prometheus/data --storage.tsdb.retention=180d --web.route-prefix=/ --web.enable-lifecycle --web.enable-admin-api] WorkingDir: Ports:[{Name:web HostPort:0 ContainerPort:9090 Protocol:TCP HostIP:}] EnvFrom:[] Env:[] Resources:{Limits:map[cpu:{i:{value:500 scale:-3} d:{Dec:<nil>} s:500m Format:DecimalSI} memory:{i:{value:524288000 scale:0} d:{Dec:<nil>} s:500Mi Format:BinarySI}] Requests:map[cpu:{i:{value:100 scale:-3} d:{Dec:<nil>} s:100m Format:DecimalSI} memory:{i:{value:209715200 scale:0} d:{Dec:<nil>} s: Format:BinarySI}]} VolumeMounts:[{Name:config ReadOnly:false MountPath:/etc/prometheus/config SubPath: MountPropagation:<nil>} {Name:rules ReadOnly:false MountPath:/etc/prometheus/rules SubPath: MountPropagation:<nil>} {Name:data ReadOnly:false MountPath:/cephfs/prometheus/data SubPath:prometheus-data MountPropagation:<nil>} {Name:prometheus-k8s-token-x8xzh ReadOnly:true MountPath:/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount SubPath: MountPropagation:<nil>}] LivenessProbe:&Probe{Handler:Handler{Exec:nil,HTTPGet:&HTTPGetAction{Path:/status,Port:web,Host:,Scheme:HTTP,HTTPHeaders:[],},TCPSocket:nil,},InitialDelaySeconds:30,TimeoutSeconds:3,PeriodSeconds:5,SuccessThreshold:1,FailureThreshold:10,} ReadinessProbe:&Probe{Handler:Handler{Exec:nil,HTTPGet:&HTTPGetAction{Path:/status,Port:web,Host:,Scheme:HTTP,HTTPHeaders:[],},TCPSocket:nil,},InitialDelaySeconds:0,TimeoutSeconds:3,PeriodSeconds:5,SuccessThreshold:1,FailureThreshold:6,} Lifecycle:nil TerminationMessagePath:/dev/termination-log TerminationMessagePolicy:File ImagePullPolicy:IfNotPresent SecurityContext:nil Stdin:false StdinOnce:false TTY:false} is dead, but RestartPolicy says that we should restart it.
    1月 20 11:22:08 k8s-3 kubelet[14306]: I0120 11:22:08.615662   14306 kuberuntime_manager.go:739] checking backoff for container "prometheus" in pod "prometheus-k8s-0_monitoring(7598959a-fcff-11e7-9333-fa163e48f857)"
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Two Prometheus servers cannot share the same storage directory, you should have gotten a locking error about this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't get a kind of locking error in my log. What should I do if I want to keep the monitoring data for a long time? Did you mean that I config the persistent volume in a wrong way, then how can I do it right?